# How will search engines react to different unicode?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, fonts, seo, search-engine

I am developing a website in the Georgian language. The Georgian alphabet has its own Unicode range, but there are also special fonts which have Georgian glyphs in place of English characters, a bit like the "Symbol" and "Dingbats" fonts.

For example the string "saqarTvelo" will be rendered as "საქართველო" with these fonts. So now I have two options and don't know what to do:

1. Using Georgian Unicode for my website, but the problem is that all fonts are created for English Unicode, and don't work with Georgian Unicode.
2. Using Georgian fonts with English Unicode. But I don't know how search engine will react.

Please tell me what to do, I am stacked!

Comment: Georgian does not have "its own Unicode". There's only *one* Unicode (the clue is in the name!), and its the same for everyone.

Comment: @Kerrek SB so what you mean? if I want to search the word "საქართველო" will google show my website? even if there is only word "saqarTvelo" which is the word "საქართველო" but only with font.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It doesn't help to pick on his poor English skills. His problem is just like the problems with the old "Symbol" and "Dingbats" fonts that re-use the ASCII range for other symbols. This was very common for just about language that doesn't use the Latin script until Unicode gained acceptance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO topics are off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that using the approach you mean in option 1, search engines will see the word “საქართველო” in your text as “saqarTvelo”, so normal searches will fail.

The question seems to refer to two different ways of using Georgian letters on web pages:

1. Using Unicode encoding, so that characters will be rendered using an Unicode-encoded font (which is what most fonts are, but most fonts don’t contain Georgian letters).
2. Using a nonstandard, “private” encoding, usually one that maps 256 different code positions (8-bit combinations) to whatever characters are needed for some purposes. This presumes that the text is rendered using a font encoded the same way.

Method 2 can be characterized as a [wrong approach](http://alis.isoc.org/web_ml/html/fontface.en.html), but it has been used on the web since the early days (even when CSS was not available and one had to resort to `<font face=...>` for setting font), and especially in the early days. It really does not work unless the user’s computer has the specific, “privately” encoded font (or some font encoded exactly the same way). Since search engines are font-agnostic, they only see the 8-bit codes and try to interpret them in the encoding declared or implied for the page, not in the “private” encoding (which cannot be declared since it has no published definition and no standard name, or any name for that matter).

Method 1 has the problem that for it to work, the user’s computer needs to have *some* (Unicode-encoded font) that supports the characters used. Nowadays, this can be reasonably well solved using a downloadable font (web font) via `@font-face`. [Fonts that support Georgian letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/10e1/fontsupport.htm) include some useful free fonts like DejaVu fonts, GNU Freefont fonts, and Quivira. For more info on this approach, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Using method 1, search engines will see the Georgian letters correctly, provided that the document’s encoding (normally UTF-8) has been properly declared or can be inferred by the search engine.

Comment: thanks a lot for helpful answer. I am planing to use Georgian font, but characters are set for English unicode, so can you tell me which program I can use to change unicode from English to Georgian?

Comment: There is no such thing as “English unicode” vs. “Georgian unicode”. You should simply use a program that lets you enter Georgian character and saves them as Unicode encoded (in practice, UTF-8 encoded). If your data is now in a “private” encoding relying on a specific privately encoded font for rendering, then you would need a documentation of that font, and then you could write a simple table-driven converter.